# Is there really a limit to sections name in PE binaries?

Tags: assembly, header, byte, portable-executable, sections

One [awesome article](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile2.html) about PE format states the following:

> *Name*. Each section header has a name field up to eight characters long, for which the first character must be a period.

But I am aware of a few examples that violates this, starting with `.gnu_debuglink` section inside binaries, that have detached debug symbols in DWARF format. Also DWARF's `.debug_arranges`, `.debug_info` and others violates this. (For comparison, PDB's "detached" section name is just `.debug`.)

So I wonder if this article is just outdated/incomplete, or maybe it's a Windows-specific guideline, or there never was any limit to section names length?

Also I would be glad if someone points to me any book about PE/COFF binaries (ELF would be great as well), more comprehensive than online articles, if it even exists. Or about system programming in general — the information about this topic is very scarce or outdated by 20+ years. :)

Comment: Was those section in a PE or in an ELF binary?

Comment: @margaret-bloom, in a PE. The question is only about PE binaries, I added the latter part about ELF only to attract more book suggestions. :)

Comment: Those names seem pretty linuxish and Dwarf was designed along with ELF (though they are independent now). The PE sections names are still limited to 8 chars.

Comment: There are only 8 bytes for the section name in PE, after that is the virtual size field. It's not a string with an arbitrary length limit, it's a qword that happens to contain a string-like value.

Comment: @harold, but looking into debugger I can see that these sections with long names have a perfectly fine virtual sizes with no jibberish values. (The binary is PE, but with those DWARF sections, it was built by mingw64's gcc — that's where the strangeness comes from.)

Comment: The name field then probably looks like "/4" or similar

Comment: @harold oh yes, this should be the answer then. Even the code that I am currently working with, recognizes the `/` in a beginning of a section name: the field for a name is indeed limited in size, but it refers to some other field, probalbly from COFF part, for a full name.

Comment: Details seem to be scarce, so far I've learned more about how it actually works from LLD (LLVMs linker) source code than any actual explanations (there don't seem to be any?)

Comment: @harold I wasn't looking hard enough though, but judging about how much information I found about this general topic, there shouldn't be any bestsellers about system programming lying around in dozens.

Btw, may I ask you to do an actual answer to this question? Because it really is one. If you don't want, I'll just answer it myself, referring to your comments here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "long section names" feature in COFF to support section names that don't fit in the section name field.

For a long section name, the normal section name field contains a name that looks like `/4`, in general a `/` followed by some decimal number as ASCII string. The number it encodes is an offset in the symbol table, so at `PointerToSymbolTable` (from the file header) plus that offset.

Answer (score 6):

There's no limit on section names in object files, but section names can't be longer than 8 bytes in executables.  From the [Microsoft Portable Executable and
Common Object File Format Specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v83.docx):

> An 8-byte, null-padded UTF-8 encoded string. If the string is exactly
>   8 characters long, there is no terminating null. For longer names, this field
>   contains a slash (/) that is followed by an ASCII representation of a decimal
>   number that is an offset into the string table. Executable images do not use a
>   string table and do not support section names longer than 8 characters. Long
>   names in object files are truncated if they are emitted to an executable file.

Note the Windows PECOFF loader ignores the names of sections, so they're not actually used for anything except as a simple form of debugging information.

Also the name doesn't have to start with a period. That's just a convention used to so they don't conflict with user defined symbols.